# How to iterate over directories in bash

Tags: bash

I have a set of directories (say a, b) with *.log files in each one.

```
pwd
a/  b/

ls a
a/1.log
a/2.log

ls b
b/3.log
b/4.dat
```

How do I iterate over all the .log files?

```
FILES=`pwd`
for f in $FILES/*.log
do
   echo $f
done
```

This just prints the dirs from the root dir but not the files within each dir.

Comment: `for f in */*.log`?

Comment: yes @Cyrus, that works, thank you!

Comment: sorry, If I have more than two levels of directories, it doesn't work

Comment: `shopt -s globstar; for f in **/*.log`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `find` command can help:

```
FILES=`pwd`
for f in `find . -name *.log`
do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).